Want to Add an ItemsControl Within a ProgressBar
I'm working on a window that follows a list of predetermined steps and displays the progress of the steps.  The requirements basically are distilled down to creating a progress bar that indicates correct steps with the usual GREEN color and then indicate incorrect steps in a RED color.  These indications will progress with each performed step with the potential to intersperse the GREEN and the RED indications.
I'm trying to do this with the ProgressBar element with an embedded ItemsControl.  I have been gathering examples on how to create this with no luck.  I do not fully understand ItemsControl and may not be approaching this in the correct way.  Here is what I have so far...
    <UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pb" Width="200" Height="15" Background="LightGray" Maximum="{Binding MaxVal}">
            <ProgressBar.Resources>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="icProgressBar" x:Key="icProgressBarKey" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="outerBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding Percent}">
                                <Grid Background="{Binding PercentColor}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Percent}"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ProgressBar.Resources>
        </ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>


And the codebehind...
        public ProgressBarWPF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            this.DataContext = new ObservableCollection<PercentItemsViewModel>()
            {
                new PercentItemsViewModel() { MaxVal = 30, Percent = 1.0, PercentColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), Total = 0.0 },
                new PercentItemsViewModel() { MaxVal = 30, Percent = 1.0, PercentColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Total = 0.0 }
            };
        }

    public class PercentItemsViewModel : Utility.PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        public PercentItemsViewModel() { }

        public double Percent
        {
            get { return (GetValue(() => Percent)); }
            set { SetValue(() => Percent, value); }
        }

        public double Total
        {
            get { return (GetValue(() => Total)); }
            set { SetValue(() => Total, value); }
        }

        public int MaxVal
        {
            get { return (GetValue(() => MaxVal)); }
            set { SetValue(() => MaxVal, value); }
        }

        public Brush PercentColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(() => PercentColor); }
            set { SetValue(() => PercentColor, value); }
        }
    }



The PercentItemsViewModel class is a child of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface that adds the Notify eventing and the GetValue and SetValue calls.
When I run this example, I do not get any indication good or bad and as I perform the defined steps, the progress bar remains "blank".  The background of the progress bar stays the standard background color.
I also tried to add the use of ProgressBar's Value property, but as I advance the value, the progress bar advances the indicator, but it remains GREEN.  In the above example, I removed the      Value={Binding Total}.
I understand I may be going down the completely wrong path, but it seems to me ItemsControl would be the perfect way to satisfy this requirement.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

<ProgressBar.Resources> is a kind of warehouse for various resources and it has no effect unless the resource there is actually used. Also <Grid.RowDefinitions> and <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> are pointless because there is no element which uses them. Said that, what is your aim to use ItemsControl to draw the bar? This simple bar can be easily drawn by the default Style of ProgressBar.

That's good to know about Rresources.  I thought that if the Resources are defined within the UI element definition, it is used.  To answer your question about why I want to do it in this way is that I want a segmented progress indication on a per-step basis with color changes that as far as I can tell the default ProgressBar does not give.  I am completely open to suggestions.

You only need the horizontal StackPanel; the rest doesn't buy you anything, The "steps" are rectangles and / or textblocks. You can change their color to show progress; or add them on the fly. If they're static, any "panel" control will work (e.g. Grid)). You could also stack checkboxes with a caption; and that "self check" with progress. Less "code".

Using ItemsControl just for drawing a ProgressBar would be overkill. Instead, you can modify the ProgressBar's Foreground to represent each segment. The following is a simple example to extend ProgressBar.
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

public record Segment(int Value, Brush Brush);

public class SegmentedProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public Segment[] Segments
    {
        get { return (Segment[])GetValue(SegmentsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SegmentsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Segments), typeof(Segment[]), typeof(SegmentedProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSegmentsChanged));

    private static void OnSegmentsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bar = (SegmentedProgressBar)d;

        var segments = (e.NewValue as Segment[])?.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToArray();
        if (segments is not { Length: > 0 })
        {
            bar.Foreground = null;
            bar.Value = 0;
            return;
        }

        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

        int start = 0;

        foreach (var segment in segments)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine(
                pen: new Pen(segment.Brush, 1),
                point0: new Point(start, 0),
                point1: new Point(segment.Value, 0));

            start = segment.Value;
        }

        drawingContext.Close();

        bar.Foreground = new VisualBrush(drawingVisual);
        bar.Value = segments.Last().Value;
    }
}

Bind this ProgressBar's Segments dependency property with array of Segment in view model. You can fill the array with as many Segments as you want.
Segment[] items = [
    new Segment(10, Brushes.Green),
    new Segment(20, Brushes.Orange),
    new Segment(40, Brushes.Red)];

To update the ProgressBar, set new array of Segment.

Thank you for your comments and answer.  I have other problems with this implementation on getting the property event handler to fire reliably.  It seems to only fire in my constructor as a test and not during run-time with actual actions to advance progress.  That is a subject of another question after trying a few things.
